# Case Insensitive for @JsonSubTypes

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = CertificateAuth.class, name = "certificate"),
        @Type(value = UsernamePasswordCredentials.class, name = "usernamepassword"),
        @Type(value = APIKeyCredentials.class, name = "apikey")
})
```

In request json, for type value how can I make that as case insensitive?

For eg: type should take "usernamepassword" (or) "userNamePassword" (or) USERNAMEPASSWORD.

Please Note:  Json to POJO mapping happens automatically as like RestController

Kindly help me

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings , you want the your `type` property in the json file is converted to the lowercase matching one of the values you wrote in your example ?

Comment: @dariosicily yes

Comment: @dariosicily Sorry for the confusion.   My request json may contain the type value in any case(lower/upper/camel). It should map the values with case insensitive.

Comment: Is there any annotations or properties which we can add it in the class to do the same?

Because, JSON to POJO mapping is handling through the annotations

Comment: There aren't no annotations or properties, an alternative is transform the `JsonNode` with the modified `type` field to a json string and then proceed as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to convert the `type` value to a lowercased string you can convert the json file to a [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) tree and after convert it to your pojo with the [`ObjectMapper#treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode-java.lang.Class-) method:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
((ObjectNode) root).put("type", root.get("type").asText().toLowerCase());
YourPojo yourPojo = mapper.treeToValue(root, YourPojo.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution. Try to configure your mapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder().enable(
        MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_VALUES,
        MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS) //in case you use enum
        .build();
```